# How to check if a command was invoked, for exam \titlepage?

Tags: beamer

I am learning how to design my own beamer theme. At present what I want to do is to be able to detect if a command like `\titlepage` was used. For example:

```
\begin{frame}[titlepage]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce a new if, which you set to be true if the command has been called. To this end you can append `\global\blablahasbeencalledtrue` to the command. For instance, for `\titlepage` you can use the following.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newif\iftitlepagehasbeencalled
\titlepagehasbeencalledfalse
\appto\titlepage{\global\titlepagehasbeencalledtrue}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    The \verb|\titlepage| command has \unless\iftitlepagehasbeencalled not\ \fi
    been called.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    The \verb|\titlepage| command has \unless\iftitlepagehasbeencalled not\ \fi 
    been called.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]